# error in the following code near throw IOException

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Propogate1
{

String reverse(String name)
{
if(name.length()==0)
    throw IOException("name");

String reverseStr="";
for(int i=name.length()-1;i>0;--i)
{
  reverseStr+=name.charAt(i);

}
return reverseStr;
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
String name;
try
{
        Propogate1 p=new Propogate1();
    p.reverse("java");

}
finally
{
System.out.println("done");
}

}

}
```

I have to create a class propogate and main method which will call reverse(). In that if the name.length is null, it will throw an exception. If it is not null it will reverse the string. Pls help me

Comment: You should not use a wildcard when importing packages. Always (there a some rare situations when you can use wildcards) use the package name + the class name you want to import (eg. import java.io.IOException). Otherwise you might have some problems with the same class name in different packages

Comment: Also there is a bug in your *for* loop which you need to fix after you follow @Guillaume's answer

Comment: @JoseK: I have removed the "for loop bug" too

Comment: Is this a homework question? If yes, tag it so.

Comment: It seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you need.

```
package reversestring;

// import java.io.* is not needed here. 
// And if you want to import anything,
// prefer specific imports instead and not entire package.

// java.lang.* is auto-imported. You needn't import it explicitly.      

public class Propogate {
  // There's no reason this method should be an object method. Make it static.
  public static String reverse(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
      // RuntimeExceptions are preferred for this kind of situations.
      // Checked exception would be inappropriate here.
      // Also, the error message should describe the kind of exception
      // occured.
      throw new RuntimeException("Empty name!");
    }
    // Idiomatic method of string reversal:
    return new StringBuilder(name).reverse().toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    try {
      name = Propogate.reverse("java");
      System.out.println("Reversed string: " + name);
    } catch (RuntimeException rx) {
      System.err.println(rx.getMessage());
    } finally {
      // I don't get the point of `finally` here. Control will reach this
      // point irrespective of whether string reversal succeeded or failed.
      // Can you explain what do you mean by "done" below?
      System.out.println("done");
    }
  }
}
```

> /*
>
> Output:-
>
> Reversed string: avaj
>
> done
>
> */

Comment: Hi thanks tat u have cleared the bug. Now in this pgm i don't want to use any catch. Without catch i have to define my own exception also i wanna use finally. Can you help me for this now

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare which exceptions are thrown in a method: the method declaration should be:

```
String reverse(String name) throws IOException
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the exception before throwing it:

```
if(name.length()==0)
    throw new IOException("name");
```

Also main must not throw an `IOException`. Catch it and print the message to `System.err`.